# How does electricity travel through saltwater

Tags: electricity

I know that electricity through normal water is a bad idea. Why not saltwater?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Your question is not very clear. Why do you think that electricity through water is a "bad idea"? What do you mean by "bad idea"? What makes you think that the situation for salt water is any different? Finally, this site is for questions about electrical engineering but your question may be more about physics or chemistry.

Comment: Salt water is more conductive than normal tap water. I think your logic is backwards. Either way, you don't want to be in the water during a thunderstorm.

Comment: Salt water is a very bad medium for radio wave propagation.

Comment: How concentrated is the salt water?  Think of the Dead Sea vs the Pacific Ocean

Comment: Electricity through water is in many, many circumstances a very good idea (salted or otherwise). Your question is flawed.

Comment: Normal tap water has ions enough to conduct as well as it is a good idea :-) I guess it is pure water which is a bad idea. You should review your question.

Answer (score 1):

Salt water is full of Na+ (sodium) and Cl- (chlorine) ions, from the dissolved salt.

If you put a positive and a negative electrode in the water, then the Cl- ions are attracted to the positive electrode, where they give up their extra electron.  The Na+ ions are attracted to the negative electrode, where they take on an elecron to make up the one they are missing.

The end result is that it looks as though elctrons are flowing from the negative electrode to the positive one, just like any other electrical conductor.  But actually, it's the dissolved ions in the water that are moving.

Pure water has very few ions - just a few H+ and OH- ions - and so is a poor conductor.